# Removing UIView from NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsarray

I have a `UIView` called `SGAdressLabel` that I store in `emailLabelsArray`.

At some point, I want to delete all the `UIViews` from their superviews while keeping them in my  array. I do a thing like this and nothing happens:

```
for (SGAdressLabel *tmpLabel in emailLabelsArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Removing labels!");
        [tmpLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

The NSLog message appears for as many times as there are objects in the Array but still, nothing happens. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
for (SGAdressLabel __strong *tmpLabel in emailLabelsArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Removing labels!");
    tempLabel = (SGAdressLabel *)tmpLabel;
    [tmpLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Also, can you NSLog(@"Removing labels = %@", tmpLabel); Put this and tell me what is the output you are getting. May be you can copy paste it here.

Comment: Same thing with the rest o your code. XCode says: `Fast enumeration variables can't be modified in ARC by default; declare the variable __strong to allow this`